# merge two function which have same property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two function which have same property. But I don't know how to merge in a one consolidate function and I tired to google it but don't know what exactly the keyword for this

```
$test  = $('.slider .pager li.slide1 a'),
$test1 = $('.slider .pagination li a')

$test.bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sliderHandler.slideFirst();
    alert("1");
});

 $test1.bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sliderHandler.slideFirst();
});
```

Its working fine for me. But I just want to make it more smaller and nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't try?

```
$test = $('.slider .pager li.slide1 a,.slider .pagination li a'),

$test.bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sliderHandler.slideFirst();
    alert("1");
});
```

In your case, just update the selector to select ***all elements*** that you need to apply the same logic.

Update:
If they are global variables already, we can try merging them:

```
$.merge( $.merge( [], $test), $test1).bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sliderHandler.slideFirst();
});
```

As pointed out by @doubleswirve in the answer below, we could also use `add` instead of `merge`: `$test.add($test1).bind('click'`

Comment: i cant merge the variable now as we are using it globally

Comment: Just to note. This is not the same as your original code. Alert doesn't happen on slide1 class.

Comment: ya ya that i got it... i was looking for pointer...that you give it to me :-)

Comment: Just to note, you don't need two selectors here. Merge, adds only complicate this simple code. Look at my code bellow.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the jQuery [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method (similar to @Khanh TO's answer):

```
// Assuming these have already been declared
$test  = $('.slider .pager li.slide1 a');
$test1 = $('.slider .pagination li a');

$test.add($test1).bind('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  sliderHandler.slideFirst();
  alert("1");
});
```

Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/doubleswirve/pen/mpItn) demonstrating a similar example.

Comment: yeahhh its working but dont know why khanh's code is not working

Comment: its perfect but i guess credit goes to khanh..with no hard feelings :-)

Comment: No problem - glad you got a solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
$test        =   $('.slider li a');

$test.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sliderHandler.slideFirst();
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('slide1'))
        alert("1");
});
```

Comment: Dont you want to merge functions and remove code duplication?

Comment: i want to reduce the size as well

Comment: Here you go, doesn't get smaller than this.